# In C, when may `fputc` return other than its first argument?

Tags: c, output, return-value, stdio

The C17 (N2176) standard states, "The fputc function returns the character written" (7.21.7.3) if there is no write error.

But in the context of

```
int c ;
// ... later, c is assigned an "interesting" value ...
int k = fputc ( c , stdout ) ;
```

is

```
k == c || k == EOF
```

always `true`? I.e., provided that `fputc` does not return `EOF`, is it guaranteed to return `c`? Put a third way, can `fputc` write a character other than one equal to its first argument?

For example If I request output of the dollar sign (not guaranteed to be in the source or execution character sets, AFAICT), could `'\u0024' != fputc('\u0024', stdout)`. Maybe the program will output a local currency symbol, instead.

### Clarification

The question is

> In C, when may `fputc` return other than its first argument?

Partial answers so far (2021-10-20) seem to be:

- when a write error occurs during `fputc`,
- when `(unsigned char) c != c`

#### I am still wondering

Suppose `(unsigned char) c == c`, but `(unsigned char) c` does not match a character in the execution character set. Is `fputc` permitted to write some other character instead?

*For example*, suppose `c == (unsigned char) '\u0024'` (ASCII dollar sign) does not exist in the execution character set (because execution character set is non-ASCII). Can `fputc` write, say, another currency symbol instead (or some arbitrary character).

Answer (score 5):

> is `k == c || k == EOF` always true?

Usually yes, but no.

With `fputc ( c , stdout )`, `c` is converted to an `unsigned char` and that is written.  It is that value or `EOF` that is returned.

Instead, expect `k == (unsigned char) c || k == EOF`.

> The `fputc` function writes the character specified by `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) to the output stream ...
> Returns:  The `fputc` function returns the character written. If a write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `fputc` returns `EOF`.  C17dr § 7.21.7.3 2-3

---

A somewhat not-so-rare example is when `ch` is assigned from a `char` that is *signed* and with a value less than 0.  The function return value is expected to be `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or `EOF`.

Example

```
char ch = -96;
printf("%d %d %d\n", SCHAR_MIN, ch, fputc(ch, stdout));
```

Output

```
�-128 -96 160
```

---

> Maybe the program will output a local currency symbol, instead.

With `fputc('\u0024', stdout)`, same as `fputc(0x24, stdout)` and `fputc(36, stdout)`, what symbol is seen is implementation specific.  C does not specify that ASCII is used, even if it is ubiquitous.  C does not specify the font nor shapes of character renderings.  Still, likely will be `$`.

Comment: +1 for `k == (unsigned char) c || k == EOF`. I am still doubtful that the standard forbids something other than this, though. Perhaps I am not being clear enough in my "dollar sign" example?

Comment: @AnaNimbus Citation added.  `$` example is clear, yet the issue is "is `k == c || k == EOF`
**always** true?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `fputc` always returns either `EOF` or the written character.

Per [cppreference.com's page on `fputc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc):

> **Return value**
> On success, returns the written character.
> On failure, returns `EOF` and sets the error indicator (see `ferror()`) on stream.

And from the C17 standard (7.21.7.3/2-3, [N2310](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)):

> 2. **Description**
>    The `fputc` function writes the character specified by c (converted to an `unsigned char`) to the output stream pointed to by stream ...
> 3. **Returns**
>    The `fputc` function returns the character written. If a write error occurs, the error indicator for the
>    stream is set and `fputc` returns `EOF`.

Comment: Very good choice of citations.

Comment: I suppose I am asking for an interpretation, as the language is to me ambiguous. _But will the written character always be equal to the one requested?_ For example, [cppreference.com/fputc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc) uses the word "success." If I write `fputc('\u0024', stdout)` and the _euro_ sign is written (rather than the dollar sign I specified), 1. does the Standard allow that, 2. would that be "success?"

Comment: Given that `c` is an `int`, and then "The `fputc` function writes the character specified by `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) ... The `fputc` function returns the character written."  the `unsigned char` that gets both written and returned **does not have to equal `c` or `EOF`**.  There are many `int` values outside the range of an `unsigned char` that are not equal to `EOF`.